# Regex PHP, Find characters in specific position

Tags: php, regex

I explain my problem : I'm working on different kind of address

```
" 25 Down Street 15000 London "

" 25 B Down Street 15000 London "

" Building A 25 Down Street 15000 London "
```

I found a way to determine which is the number of the street on all case with this regex :

```
 `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\s*[A-Z])?)\b`
```

But now i got a problem that i can't solve, i need when the case is real to determine characters which are before the street's number .

Example : " **Building 2** 25 Down Street 15000 London " i need here to find only **"Building 2"**

I understand that i have to find characters before the first number of this string.

Keep searching on my own but will be great if someone got a solution for me .

Thank you .

Edit my code now is :

```
preg_match('/^(.*?)\d+\s+\D+/', $cleanAdressNode, $result, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,0);
        print $result[0][0];

        return $result[0][0];
```

and the result now is : Résidence Les Thermes 1 15 boulevard Jean Jaurès instead of only : **Résidence Les Thermes 1**

Comment: Matching addresses using regular expressions is near impossible... it would take a purpose-built system to figure out what each token in the string means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^(\D*)/', $str, $match);
```

You will find in `$match[1]` everything that is not a digit at the begining of the string.

According to your example:

```
preg_match('/^(.*?)\d+\s+\D+/', $str, $match);
```

Comment: I found a way to do it look at this : https://regex101.com/r/nU5tA7/1
But my new problem is that i can have special characters like "é" or "ç" and my regex don't work anymore with this look at this example : https://regex101.com/r/yB1hI0/1 maybe you can help me with this ?

Comment: @VERYNET: I can't help you without seeing your code. Edit your question add the relevant part of the code, some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: @VERYNET: the result is in the first group ie. `$result[1][0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the first non-numeric characters, `^([^0-9]*)` should do the trick. It uses class negation to grab every non-numeric characters at the start of the string.

Comment: I found a way to do it look at this : regex101.com/r/nU5tA7/1 But my new problem is that i can have special characters like "é" or "ç" and my regex don't work anymore with this look at this example : regex101.com/r/yB1hI0/1 maybe you can help me with this ?

Comment: Here you're looking for the two groups "Résidence les Thermes 1" and "25 B Boulevard Emile Zola 13100 Aix en Provence" right?

Comment: Only for : "Résidence les Thermes 1" , it's the only match

Comment: The 1 really is problematic, as there is no formal way to distinguish it from the street number... Let me think about it

Comment: It's seems to be resolved look at @Toto edit it works pretty well .

Comment: Now it won't work anymore if you remove the 1 though - nevermind, it works. I'm still pretty sure there's a problem though, let me check

Comment: @VERYNET Ok so toto's suggestion will work most of the time, but will break for some addresses like "Résidence les Thermes 1 - 2 25 B Boulevard Emile Zola 13100 Aix en Provence". I'm not sure there's much more to do though, address parsing isn't easy and depends a lot of the format of the data you have

Comment: At least there is no specific characters like "-" it's definitly sure . i'm searching for something working most of time so this must be good for me . Tahnk you anyway

Comment: Okay I've found an annoying problem : it won't work if there is something else than a space just after the street number. Which happens often enough with bis, ter, etc.